# Android : Problem with OnGlobalLayout

Tags: java, android, textview

In my code i m trying to find the height the textview occupies..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t = new TextView(this);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = t.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    t.setText("This is to test the text\n Some Text \n Another ..");
    t.append("\nafter something");
    Toast.makeText(this, " The value at num = "+num,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(t);
}

public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    num=t.getHeight();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hellooo !! height is "+num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The value of num in onCreate() is always zero but atlast in the onGlobalLayout() , the correct height is getting stored in num but i cant use it because it is the end of the application ..
Is there any possibility of getting the text length in the middle of the application ?

Forgive, if there are any mistakes in the above problem..

Thanks,
Siva Kuamr

Comment: Any solutions please ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the end of the application, that's when Android has finished layout. If you need that to be the "middle" of the application, call in `onGlobalLayout()` some method that will use the height value. See [Event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).